# Using scope in Angular directive templates

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a problem in that I need to toggle some classes based on a value that can only be determined once the template has been compiled.

That's probably not a very helpful description but I'm not sure what the best way to do this is so I have prepared a plunkr.

http://plnkr.co/edit/zfwWOdOcNGD2At8rjS1q?p=preview

The part that I'm interested in is at the bottom of app.js:

```
app.directive('page', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        replace: true,
        require: '^pager',
        template: '<div class="page" ng-class="{\'ng-show\': page >= index, \'page-next\': (page + 1) === index}"></div>',
        compile: function (element, attributes) {
            return function(scope) {
                scope.index = attributes.index;
                scope.addPage(element);
            };
        }
    }
});
```

You can see in the template I need to toggle some classes based on what order they were added in. However the issue I'm running into is that all of the scopes seem to have an index of 6.

I also don't know if this is the correct way so I'm open to suggestions on how to improve this code to make it more "angular"-y.

Comment: If they are sibling directives in the markup, then they have the same scope instance. You can either use an isolate scope or transclude to clone the element and force a child scope

Comment: If I set it up as an isolated scope, is it possible to pass in a reference to the `addPage` method on the parent scope?